# Data entry using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to submit data on some HTML page using VBA. The HTML page contains some Java scripts and it is a secured page.

I tried to use the codes below, but it only opens the website window and doesn't fill out any texts on the page.

I know I still need to add codes for loginname/password valification, msgbox (for stop control), submit button click codes.

Could someone help?

```
Sub Tes()
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim TrackID As Object

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    IE.navigate "https://abcxxx.com/xxxx/xxxxxxx/Pages/CustInfo.aspx"

    IE.Visible = True

    Do Until IE.readystate = 4: DoEvents: Loop

    Set TrackID = IE.document.getelementbyid("abc00_abc001_234_5678_81b0_txtCustomerNo")

    TrackID.Value = Range("A2").Value

    TrackID.form.submit

End Sub
```

:::header informaion:::

```
<head id="ctl00_HEAD1"></head>
<body onload="javascript:if (typeof(_spBodyOnLoadWrapper) != 'undefined') _spBodyOnLoadWrapper();" scroll="yes">
    <form id="xxxForm" onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();" action="/xxxx/xxxxxxx/Pages/CustInfo.aspx" method="post" name="xxxForm">

<div></div>
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/WebResource.axd?d=l9_fanifTkSGPMjqQJxGzkhm0A9CUTq0e2fMvidi8…mlhiyeYfbecR_SY_yD1HlOp8dnx1WI0dTdidvw1&t=634605258709717464"></script>
<script></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript"></script>
<script></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/WebResource.axd?d=wAwuGCcAd8-EEHMrxtDWcHPpbrIz4dtxvSld4vGrJ…1WyuhxU_XTb_KI5FuNTSBKr7UJL75sqY7cXp281&t=634605258709717464"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/WebResource.axd?d=zXhglhR5yBgSmErqplHM82fD2Jq9gJIaO6HzhlL5E…MnKMvLQ-2WyEUUcPnCWpgOMpxqYDqDmsApddeA1&t=634605258709717464"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: If you are unable to provide the 'landing page' of the site where you want to submit form information then unfortunately there is very little that can be offered short of throwing mud at a wall to see what sticks. Suggest yu get [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) and use it to get the information that will uniquely identify each HTML element and response header you require.

Comment: Thank you Jeeped, does this give enough information?

Comment: Please edit your question to include code. The recent additions in the comments section are very hard to read.

Comment: No, I was trying to add the header information. Sorry, this is hard to follow, but wasn't sure where to add this.

Comment: OK, I moved the header info.

Answer (score 0):

You have redacted the actual website address so no one can actually find out what you are doing wrong.  But your method appears to be fine - the same code works for me on another website:

```
Sub main()
  Dim IE As Object
  Dim TrackID As Object
  Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
  IE.navigate "http://www.wikipedia.org/"
  IE.Visible = True
  Do Until IE.readystate = 4: DoEvents: Loop
  Set searchInput = IE.document.getelementbyid("searchInput")
  searchInput.Value = "Visual Basic for Applications"
  searchInput.form.submit
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, Jerry. It is a secured site and you wouldn't be able to see the actual page, but I added the header info in the question. It seems I need to change something to be able to let this work on my page.

Answer (score 0):

You have a form with the redacted name *xxxForm*. If all of the input elements you wish to set values to are children of this form, I would set an object to the form and use it as the parent.

I prefer to work with the Microsoft HTML element declarations. You may need the VBE's Tools ► References *Microsoft Internet Controls* and *Microsoft HTML object library* added to your project.

```
Sub Tes()
    Dim IE As new SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim eTrackForm As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    IE.navigate "https://abcxxx.com/xxxx/xxxxxxx/Pages/CustInfo.aspx"

    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Silent = True

    Do while ie.busy or IE.readystate <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    Set eTrackForm = IE.document.getelementbyid("xxxForm")

    if not eTrackForm is nothing then
        with eTrackForm
            .getelementbyid("ID_of_the_name_input").value = "Me"
            .getelementbyid("ID_of_the_password_input").value = "MyPass"
            .getelementbyid("abc00_abc001_234_5678_81b0_txtCustomerNo").value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value
            .submit
        end with
    end if

End Sub
```

That looks like it should get you past the first credentials input form once you've changed my generic credentials and input element IDs to the actuals ones. There is nothing magical here. In fact there is very little difference between this, your code or other code submitted here as a possible solution.